# I don't know how the colon and question mark works in this code

Tags: c

```
int main(void) 
{ 
    int arr[] = { 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 }; 
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
    int x = 2; 
    int result = binarySearch(arr, 0, n - 1, x); 
    (result == -1) ? printf("Element is not present in array") 
                   : printf("Element is present at index %d", 
                            result); 
    return 0; 
}
```

so right beside the (result==-1) is the ? and : . now i've never seen these things before and don't know how they work, are they like True of false statements or like switch-cases?

Comment: This is not a tutorial site.

Comment: The ?: is designed for returning a value to an expression.  What they did here was make an if statement and then obfuscate it on purpose for no advantage.  If it can be done in a more readable way, then it should be.  I wouldn't call this the most readable way...

Answer (score 0):

These are ternary operator, a quick shorthand for `if...else`:

```
(condition) ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

Comment: This is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score -1):

Its calles ternary operator.  If-else equivalent

```
if(result == -1) 
    printf("Element is not present in array") ;
else
    printf("Element is present at index %d",  result);
```

It doesn't mean you can write everything that way. Each statement after ? Mark must have to return a value. Printf function teturns int, the number of characters it printed. Hence this is working. If you pass a void function you will see compilation error.